# how to set up ssh tunnel to acces administartion space

Tags: security, ssh, iptables, ssh-tunnel, putty

My administration space  is accessible via a specific port (4848) and I want to block this port to increse security .

I have already disabled remote access to my database too and acces it via ssh tunnel .

Is it possible to make the same thing for my http server administration space ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can configure your admin web page to be accessible only from `localhost`, you can just set up basic port forwarding:

```
ssh -L 4848:127.0.0.1:4848 username@yourhost.com
```

from your client and access it on your browser via `http(s)://localhost:4848`

Comment: I tried it. It workd and when I look to the log I see that my the server connect to itslef using his external ip not localhost . Can I change this behaviour because I'm blocking all external trafic to the port and this can be a problem if pirate use ip spoof to connect ?